# Call $http.post in $scope function are not working

Tags: angularjs, api, http, scope

I'm trying to call an API Url from a $scope function but it's not calling it and there are no errors on the console

this is my code :
1- angularjs function :

```
 $scope.AddPin = function (Xlocation, Ylocation) {
             debugger;
            var sceneid = AframeAPIController1.sceneID;
            var data = { id: sceneid};
            $http.post('/Umbraco/Api/AframeVrApi/InsertNewPin', JSON.stringify(data));
```

2- calling the function from JS in my HTML page:

```
var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('fulldiv')).scope();
 scope.AddPin(X, Y);
```

Comment: Does it reach the `debugger; `?

Comment: yes it does, but it doesn't call the API Method

Comment: I think the `$http.post` is missing a baseurl like for ex. `$http.post('http://localhost/Umbraco/Api/AframeVrApi/InsertNewPin', JSON.stringify(data));`, because of that it doesnt hit anything.

Comment: Check the API is getting called or not in the Network tab of Developer's Tool.